# C# with Visual FoxPro database

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro

I try to make a c# application that works with visual foxpro databases. How can I list the tables from the database after I make the connection?

Comment: [DbConnection.GetSchema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.getschema(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the table names? If so, since the VFP is a file based database system, you could simply use the Directory.GetFiles(). ie:

```
string sourcePath = @"C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL FOXPRO 9\samples\Northwind";
var allFiles = from f in Directory
   .GetFiles(sourcePath,
   "*.DBF",
   SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
   select f;
```

This would find all the tables in a directory, regardless the tables are member of a database or not.

Note: This is NOT looking for tables, that are part of the database in your connection. A database's tables might be on different folders (very much unlikely). Depending on your real purpose, it might matter (with VFP you would unlikely want to use database dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database, that means that you have a .dbc file on your disk wich is essentially a table containing all the info about tables in database.
So open that as a table and execute:

SELECT objectname FROM your_database_name WHERE objecttype="Table".

It will give you all the table names from that database.

Answer (score 0):

see this code below

```
var foxProConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionStringHere);

                        await foxProConnection.OpenAsync();

                        if (foxProConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            var tablesNames = foxProConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            var viewsNames = foxProConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Views, null);
                            var dataTable = new DataTable();
                            dataTable.Columns.Add("TABLE_NAME");

                            //Fill Tables Names
                            if (tablesNames != null)
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow row in tablesNames.Rows)
                                {
                                    dataTable.Rows.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

                                }
                            }

                            //Fill Views Names
                            if (viewsNames != null)
                            {
                                foreach (DataRow row in viewsNames.Rows)
                                {
                                    dataTable.Rows.Add(row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString());

                                }
                            }

                            return dataTable;
                        }
```